# any short form for calling namespace inside the function

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces

I use armadillo matrix library to assign a vector such as:

```
mid(mids::input1)=....
mid(mids::input2)=....
mid(mids::input3)=....
mid(mids::input4)=....
mid(mids::input5)=....
mid(mids::input6)=....
```

here `mid` is a vector and its functor mixed with `operator =` is something similar to `mid[...]` to assigns values to the specific index of vector.

and `mids` is a namespace. Since, I use pattern of `mid(mids:....)` a lot, I am wondering if there is any way to avoid writing long and making it shorter such as:

```
mid(input6)=...
```

in another word, inside functor of `mid`, I want that namespace `mids` be considered.

Is there any C++11 (or below) solution for it?

I don't like using macro. I dont like opening a `using namespace mids;` to for the whole codes.

I just need `using namespace mids;` inside `mid` functor.

Comment: Did you try putting `using namespace mids;` in that function?

Comment: @MikeSeymour I dont think it affects the calling point.

Comment: I meant the function that's calling `mid` many times. Or some scope (narrower than "the whole codes") that contains all the functions that call `mid`.

Comment: the problem is name conflict happens. here namespace `mids` and `states` have a lot of names in common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put `using namespace mids;` in the scope you want to make all names visible in. It will not make anything visible outside of that scope. Example:

```
void fun1 () {
    using namespace mids;
    auto v = input1;  // Ok, finds mids::input1
}

void fun2 () {
    auto v = input1;  // Error, cannot see mids::input1
}
```

of even

```
void fun () {
    mid.input(input1); // Error
    {
        using namespace mids;
        mid.input(input1); // Ok
    }
    mid.input(input1); // Error
}
```

Comment: do you mean putting `using namespace mids;` inside the implemented code? then, does it affect calling point?

Comment: @ar2015 added an example to clarify.

Comment: it works only inside the function but not at the place where i call `func1`. did i get the point correctly?

Comment: @ar2015 Yes, you are supposed to put it in the scope where you want to *use* the names, not in the function you call. That means, put it in the scope where you do this `mid.insert(mids::input1);` stuff.